# Amazon Echo trouble with Integers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I developed an AWS Lambda function for an Alexa Skill, some of the utterances are expecting an integer. Echo is most of the times confusing "two" as "to" and "four" as "for", eight as "ate". So far the only solution I could come up with is to say the word "number" before the actual number and the problem is fixed. However I was wondering if there is some other way to fix this without having to say the word "number" and adding it to my utterances. I could not find a solution online for this.

Comment: Perhaps you can try evaluating each "number-word" with regard to the context that it's used in.  If there is no context provided, I don't think Alexa will be able to distinguish.

Comment: Are you using the `AMAZON.Number` slot type for your integers? https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/built-in-intent-ref/slot-type-reference#numbers-dates-and-times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMAZON.NUMBER did not work. What worked for me was writing a method that changed words to integers it also handles the 'to', 'for', 'ate', etc... problem. A bit tedious to write but it worked at least. The following is the JavaScript code I used

```
 var Small=

{

 '1' : 1,
 '2' : 2,
 '3' : 3,
 '4' : 4,
 '5' : 5,
 '6' : 6,
 '7' : 7,
 '8' : 8,
 '9' : 9,
 '10' : 10,
 '11' : 11,
 '12' : 12,
 '13' : 13,
 '14' : 14,
 '15' : 15,
 '16' : 16,
 '17' : 17,
 '18' : 18,
 '19' : 19,
 '20' : 20,
 '21' : 21,
 '22' : 22,
 '23' : 23,
 '24' : 24,
 '25' : 25,
 '26' : 26,
 '27' : 27,
 '28' : 28,
 '29' : 29,
 '30' : 30,
 '31' : 31,
 '32' : 32,
 '33' : 33,
 '34' : 34,
 '35' : 35,
 '36' : 36,
 '37' : 37,
 '38' : 38,
 '39' : 39,
 '40' : 40,
 '41' : 41,
 '42' : 42,
 '43' : 43,
 '44' : 44,
 '45' : 45,
 '46' : 46,
 '47' : 47,
 '48' : 48,
 '49' : 49,
 '50' : 50,
 '51' : 51,
 '52' : 52,
 '53' : 53,
 '54' : 54,
 '55' : 55,
 '56' : 56,
 '57' : 57,
 '58' : 58,
 '59' : 59,
 '60' : 60,
 '61' : 61,
 '62' : 62,
 '63' : 63,
 '64' : 64,
 '65' : 65,
 '66' : 66,
 '67' : 67,
 '68' : 68,
 '69' : 69,
 '70' : 70,
 '71' : 71,
 '72' : 72,
 '73' : 73,
 '74' : 74,
 '75' : 75,
 '76' : 76,
 '77' : 77,
 '78' : 78,
 '79' : 79,
 '80' : 80,
 '81' : 81,
 '82' : 82,
 '83' : 83,
 '84' : 84,
 '85' : 85,
 '86' : 86,
 '87' : 87,
 '88' : 88,
 '89' : 89,
 '90' : 90,
 '91' : 91,
 '92' : 92,
 '93' : 93,
 '94' : 94,
 '95' : 95,
 '96' : 96,
 '97' : 97,
 '98' : 98,
 '99' : 99,
 '100' : 100,
 '101' : 101,
 '102' : 102,
 '103' : 103,
 '104' : 104,
 '105' : 105,
 '106' : 106,
 '107' : 107, 
 '108' : 108,
 '109' : 109,
 '110' : 110,
 '111' : 111,
 '112' : 112,
 '113' : 113,
 '114' : 114,
 '115' : 115,
 '116' : 116,
 '117' : 117,
 '118' : 118,
 '119' : 119,
 '120' : 120,
 '121' : 121,
 '122' : 122,
 '123' : 123,
 '124' : 124,
 '125' : 125,
 '126' : 126,
 '127' : 127,
 '128' : 128,
 '129' : 129,
 '130' : 130,
 '131' : 131,
 '132' : 132,
 '133' : 133,
 '134' : 134,
 '135' : 135,
 '136' : 136,
 '137' : 137,
 '138' : 138,
 '139' : 139,
 '140' : 140,
 '141' : 141,
 '142' : 142,
 '143' : 143,
 '144' : 144,
 '145' : 145,
 '146' : 146,
 '147' : 147,
 '148' : 148,
 '149' : 149,
 '150' : 150,
 '151' : 151,
 '152' : 152,
 '153' : 153,
 '154' : 154,
 '155' : 155,
 '156' : 156,
 '157' : 157,
 '158' : 158,
 '159' : 159,
 '160' : 160,
 '161' : 161,
 '162' : 162,
 '163' : 163,
 '164' : 164,
 '165' : 165,
 '166' : 166,
 '167' : 167,
 '168' : 168,
 '169' : 169,
 '170' : 170,
 '171' : 171,
 '172' : 172,
 '173' : 173,
 '174' : 174,
 '175' : 175,
 '176' : 176,
 '177' : 177,
 '178' : 178,
 '179' : 179,
 '180' : 180,
 '181' : 181,
 '182' : 182,
 '183' : 183,
 '184' : 184,
 '185' : 185,
 '186' : 186,
 '187' : 187,
 '188' : 188,
 '189' : 189,
 '190' : 190,
 '191' : 191,
 '192' : 192,
 '193' : 193,
 '194' : 194,
 '195' : 195,
 '196' : 196,
 '197' : 197,
 '198' : 198,
 '199' : 199,
 '200' : 200,
 '201' : 201,
 '202' : 202,
 '203' : 203,
 '204' : 204,
 '205' : 205,
 '206' : 206,
 '207' : 207,
 '208' : 208,
 '209' : 209,
 '210' : 210,
 '211' : 211,
 '212' : 212,
 '213' : 213,
 '214' : 214,
 '215' : 215,
 '216' : 216,
 '217' : 217,
 '218' : 218,
 '219' : 219,
 '220' : 220,
 '221' : 221,
 '222' : 222,
 '223' : 223,
 '224' : 224,
 '225' : 225,
 '226' : 226,
 '227' : 227,
 '228' : 228,
 '229' : 229,
 '230' : 230,
 '231' : 231,
 '232' : 232,
 '233' : 233,
 '234' : 234,
 '235' : 235,
 '236' : 236,
 '237' : 237,
 '238' : 238,
 '239' : 239,
 '240' : 240,
 '241' : 241,
 '242' : 242,
 '243' : 243,
 '244' : 244,
 '245' : 245,
 '246' : 246,
 '247' : 247,
 '248' : 248,
 '249' : 249,
 '250' : 250,
 '251' : 251,
 '252' : 252,
 '253' : 253,
 '254' : 254,
 '255' : 255,
 '256' : 256,
 '257' : 257,
 '258' : 258,
 '259' : 259,
 '260' : 260,
 '261' : 261,
 '262' : 262,
 '263' : 263,
 '264' : 264,
 '265' : 265,
 '266' : 266,
 '267' : 267,
 '268' : 268,
 '269' : 269,
 '270' : 270,
 '271' : 271,
 '272' : 272,
 '273' : 273,
 '274' : 274,
 '275' : 275,
 '276' : 276,
 '277' : 277,
 '278' : 278,
 '279' : 279,
 '280' : 280,
 '281' : 281,
 '282' : 282,
 '283' : 283,
 '284' : 284,
 '285' : 285,
 '286' : 286,
 '287' : 287,
 '288' : 288,
 '289' : 289,
 '290' : 290,
 '291' : 291,
 '292' : 292,
 '293' : 293,
 '294' : 294,
 '295' : 295,
 '296' : 296,
 '297' : 297,
 '298' : 298,
 '299' : 299,
 '300' : 300,
 '301' : 301,
 '302' : 302,
 '303' : 303,
 '304' : 304,
 '305' : 305,
 '306' : 306,
 '307' : 307,
 '308' : 308,
 '309' : 309,
 '310' : 310,
 '311' : 311,
 '312' : 312,
 '313' : 313,
 '314' : 314,
 '315' : 315,
 '316' : 316,
 '317' : 317,
 '318' : 318,
 '319' : 319,
 '320' : 320,
 '321' : 321,
 '322' : 322,
 '323' : 323,
 '324' : 324,
 '325' : 325,
 '326' : 326,
 '327' : 327,
 '328' : 328,
 '329' : 329,
 '330' : 330,
 '331' : 331,
 '332' : 332,
 '333' : 333,
 '334' : 334,
 '335' : 335,
 '336' : 336,
 '337' : 337,
 '338' : 338,
 '339' : 339,
 '340' : 340,
 '341' : 341,
 '342' : 342,
 '343' : 343,
 '344' : 344,
 '345' : 345,
 '346' : 346,
 '347' : 347,
 '348' : 348,
 '349' : 349,
 '350' : 350,
 '351' : 351,
 '352' : 352,
 '353' : 353,
 '354' : 354,
 '355' : 355,
 '356' : 356,
 '357' : 357,
 '358' : 358,
 '359' : 359,
 '360' : 360,
 '361' : 361,
 '362' : 362,
 '363' : 363,
 '364' : 364,
 '365' : 365,
 '366' : 366,
 '367' : 367,
 '368' : 368,
 '369' : 369,
 '370' : 370,
 '371' : 371,
 '372' : 372,
 '373' : 373,
 '374' : 374,
 '375' : 375,
 '376' : 376,
 '377' : 377,
 '378' : 378,
 '379' : 379,
 '380' : 380,
 '381' : 381,
 '382' : 382,
 '383' : 383,
 '384' : 384,
 '385' : 385,
 '386' : 386,
 '387' : 387,
 '388' : 388,
 '389' : 389,
 '390' : 390,
 '391' : 391,
 '392' : 392,
 '393' : 393,
 '394' : 394,
 '395' : 395,
 '396' : 396,
 '397' : 397,
 '398' : 398,
 '399' : 399,
 '400' : 400,
 '401' : 401,
 '402' : 402,
 '403' : 403,
 '404' : 404,
 '405' : 405,
 '406' : 406,
 '407' : 407,
 '408' : 408,
 '409' : 409,
 '410' : 410,
 '411' : 411,
 '412' : 412,
 '413' : 413,
 '414' : 414,
 '415' : 415,
 '416' : 416,
 '417' : 417,
 '418' : 418,
 '419' : 419,
 '420' : 420,
 '421' : 421,
 '422' : 422,
 '423' : 423,
 '424' : 424,
 '425' : 425,
 '426' : 426,
 '427' : 427,
 '428' : 428,
 '429' : 429,
 '430' : 430,
 '431' : 431,
 '432' : 432,
 '433' : 433,
 '434' : 434,
 '435' : 435,
 '436' : 436,
 '437' : 437,
 '438' : 438,
 '439' : 439,
 '440' : 440,
 '441' : 441,
 '442' : 442,
 '443' : 443,
 '444' : 444,
 '445' : 445,
 '446' : 446,
 '447' : 447,
 '448' : 448,
 '449' : 449,
 '450' : 450,
 '451' : 451,
 '452' : 452,
 '453' : 453,
 '454' : 454,
 '455' : 455,
 '456' : 456,
 '457' : 457,
 '458' : 458,
 '459' : 459,
 '460' : 460,
 '461' : 461,
 '462' : 462,
 '463' : 463,
 '464' : 464,
 '465' : 465,
 '466' : 466,
 '467' : 467,
 '468' : 468,
 '469' : 469,
 '470' : 470,
 '471' : 471,
 '472' : 472,
 '473' : 473,
 '474' : 474,
 '475' : 475,
 '476' : 476,
 '477' : 477,
 '478' : 478,
 '479' : 479,
 '480' : 480,
 '481' : 481,
 '482' : 482,
 '483' : 483,
 '484' : 484,
 '485' : 485,
 '486' : 486,
 '487' : 487,
 '488' : 488,
 '489' : 489,
 '490' : 490,
 '491' : 491,
 '492' : 492,
 '493' : 493,
 '494' : 494,
 '495' : 495,
 '496' : 496,
 '497' : 497,
 '498' : 498,
 '499' : 499,
 '500' : 500,
 '501' : 501,
 '502' : 502,
 '503' : 503,
 '504' : 504,
 '505' : 505,
 '506' : 506,
 '507' : 507,
 '508' : 508,
 '509' : 509,
 '510' : 510,
 '511' : 511,
 '512' : 512,
 '513' : 513,
 '514' : 514,
 '515' : 515,
 '516' : 516,
 '517' : 517,
 '518' : 518,
 '519' : 519,
 '520' : 520,
 '521' : 521,
 '522' : 522,
 '523' : 523,
 '524' : 524,
 '525' : 525,
 '526' : 526,
 '527' : 527,
 '528' : 528,
 '529' : 529,
 '530' : 530,
 '531' : 531,
 '532' : 532,
 '533' : 533,
 '534' : 534,
 '535' : 535,
 '536' : 536,
 '537' : 537,
 '538' : 538,
 '539' : 539,
 '540' : 540,
 '541' : 541,
 '542' : 542,
 '543' : 543,
 '544' : 544,
 '545' : 545,
 '546' : 546,
 '547' : 547,
 '548' : 548,
 '549' : 549,
 '550' : 550,
 '551' : 551,
 '552' : 552,
 '553' : 553,
 '554' : 554,
 '555' : 555,
 '556' : 556,
 '557' : 557,
 '558' : 558,
 '559' : 559,
 '560' : 560,
 '561' : 561,
 '562' : 562,
 '563' : 563,
 '564' : 564,
 '565' : 565,
 '566' : 566,
 '567' : 567,
 '568' : 568,
 '569' : 569,
 '570' : 570,
 '571' : 571,
 '572' : 572,
 '573' : 573,
 '574' : 574,
 '575' : 575,
 '576' : 576,
 '577' : 577,
 '578' : 578,
 '579' : 579,
 '580' : 580,
 '581' : 581,
 '582' : 582,
 '583' : 583,
 '584' : 584,
 '585' : 585,
 '586' : 586,
 '587' : 587,
 '588' : 588,
 '589' : 589,
 '590' : 590,
 '591' : 591,
 '592' : 592,
 '593' : 593,
 '594' : 594,
 '595' : 595,
 '596' : 596,
 '597' : 597,
 '598' : 598,
 '599' : 599,
 '600' : 600,
 '601' : 601,
 '602' : 602,
 '603' : 603,
 '604' : 604,
 '605' : 605,
 '606' : 606,
 '607' : 607,
 '608' : 608,
 '609' : 609,
 '610' : 610,
 '611' : 611,
 '612' : 612,
 '613' : 613,
 '614' : 614,
 '615' : 615,
 '616' : 616,
 '617' : 617,
 '618' : 618,
 '619' : 619,
 '620' : 620,
 '621' : 621,
 '622' : 622,
 '623' : 623,
 '624' : 624,
 '625' : 625,
 '626' : 626,
 '627' : 627,
 '628' : 628,
 '629' : 629,
 '630' : 630,
 '631' : 631,
 '632' : 632,
 '633' : 633,
 '634' : 634,
 '635' : 635,
 '636' : 636,
 '637' : 637,
 '638' : 638,
 '639' : 639,
 '640' : 640,
 '641' : 641,
 '642' : 642,
 '643' : 643,
 '644' : 644,
 '645' : 645,
 '646' : 646,
 '647' : 647,
 '648' : 648,
 '649' : 649,
 '650' : 650,
 '651' : 651,
 '652' : 652,
 '653' : 653,
 '654' : 654,
 '655' : 655,
 '656' : 656,
 '657' : 657,
 '658' : 658,
 '659' : 659,
 '660' : 660,
 '661' : 661,
 '662' : 662,
 '663' : 663,
 '664' : 664,
 '665' : 665,
 '666' : 666,
 '667' : 667,
 '668' : 668,
 '669' : 669,
 '670' : 670,
 '671' : 671,
 '672' : 672,
 '673' : 673,
 '674' : 674,
 '675' : 675,
 '676' : 676,
 '677' : 677,
 '678' : 678,
 '679' : 679,
 '680' : 680,
 '681' : 681,
 '682' : 682,
 '683' : 683,
 '684' : 684,
 '685' : 685,
 '686' : 686,
 '687' : 687,
 '688' : 688,
 '689' : 689,
 '690' : 690,
 '691' : 691,
 '692' : 692,
 '693' : 693,
 '694' : 694,
 '695' : 695,
 '696' : 696,
 '697' : 697,
 '698' : 698,
 '699' : 699,
 '700' : 700,
 '701' : 701,
 '702' : 702,
 '703' : 703,
 '704' : 704,
 '705' : 705,
 '706' : 706,
 '707' : 707,
 '708' : 708,
 '709' : 709,
 '710' : 710,
 '711' : 711,
 '712' : 712,
 '713' : 713,
 '714' : 714,
 '715' : 715,
 '716' : 716,
 '717' : 717,
 '718' : 718,
 '719' : 719,
 '720' : 720,
 '721' : 721,
 '722' : 722,
 '723' : 723,
 '724' : 724,
 '725' : 725,
 '726' : 726,
 '727' : 727,
 '728' : 728,
 '729' : 729,
 '730' : 730,
 '731' : 731,
 '732' : 732,
 '733' : 733,
 '734' : 734,
 '735' : 735,
 '736' : 736,
 '737' : 737,
 '738' : 738,
 '739' : 739,
 '740' : 740,
 '741' : 741,
 '742' : 742,
 '743' : 743,
 '744' : 744,
 '745' : 745,
 '746' : 746,
 '747' : 747,
 '748' : 748,
 '749' : 749,
 '750' : 750,
 '751' : 751,
 '752' : 752,
 '753' : 753,
 '754' : 754,
 '755' : 755,
 '756' : 756,
 '757' : 757,
 '758' : 758,
 '759' : 759,
 '760' : 760,
 '761' : 761,
 '762' : 762,
 '763' : 763,
 '764' : 764,
 '765' : 765,
 '766' : 766,
 '767' : 767,
 '768' : 768,
 '769' : 769,
 '770' : 770,
 '771' : 771,
 '772' : 772,
 '773' : 773,
 '774' : 774,
 '775' : 775,
 '776' : 776,
 '777' : 777,
 '778' : 778,
 '779' : 779,
 '780' : 780,
 '781' : 781,
 '782' : 782,
 '783' : 783,
 '784' : 784,
 '785' : 785,
 '786' : 786,
 '787' : 787,
 '788' : 788,
 '789' : 789,
 '790' : 790,
 '791' : 791,
 '792' : 792,
 '793' : 793,
 '794' : 794,
 '795' : 795,
 '796' : 796,
 '797' : 797,
 '798' : 798,
 '799' : 799,
 '800' : 800,
 'zero': 0,
 'oh': 0,
 'o': 0,
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
    'to': 2,
    'three': 3,
    'four': 4,
    'for': 4,
    'five': 5,
    'six': 6,
    'sticks': 6,
    'seven': 7,
    'eight': 8,
    'ate': 8,
    'nine': 9,
    'ten': 10,
    'eleven': 11,
    'twelve': 12,
    'thirteen': 13,
    'fourteen': 14,
    'fifteen': 15,
    'sixteen': 16,
    'seventeen': 17,
    'eighteen': 18,
    'nineteen': 19,
    'twenty': 20,
    'thirty': 30,
    'forty': 40,
    'fifty': 50,
    'sixty': 60,
    'seventy': 70,
    'eighty': 80,
    'ninety': 90,
    'hundred': null,
    
};
```

I added the numbers just to be on the safe side and since the project I was working on only required 3 digit numbers (Course Numbers) I didn't have to go any further and thought it a good idea to just put those few hundred numbers. Clearly not a good idea for all numbers.

```
function text2num(s)

 {
  var array = s.toString().split(/[\s-]+/);
      var num=0;
       var a;
       var index=0;
        if(s.includes('hundred')){
        while(index<array.length){
        a=array[index];
        index++;
            if(a.includes('and')===false){
        num= feach(a, num, 0);
            }
        
    }
    return num;

    }else if(s.includes('ty') ){
        var d=100;
        while(index<array.length){
            a=array[index];
            
            index++;
                    if(a.includes('and')===false){
            num=feach(a, num, 0)*d;
            d=1;
                    }
        }
        return num;
    }else{
        var n='';

        while(index<array.length){
        a=array[index];
            if(a.includes('and')===false){
        n= n + feach(a, num, 0);
            }
        index++;
        }
        return n;
    }
    
    }
function feach(w, g, n ) {
        var x;
        var x = Small[w];
        if (x !== null) {
            g = g + x;
                return g;
        }
        else{
            g = g * 100;
                return g;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `AMAZON.Number` slot type for your integers. This slot type will convert numeric words into digits, and may be able to help with these similar-sounding words.

**Sample Intent:**

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "MyIntent",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "myvalue",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Sample Utterance:**

```
MyIntent The number is {myvalue}
```

### Further Reading

- [Alexa Documentation - Slot Type Reference: Numbers, Dates, and Times](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/built-in-intent-ref/slot-type-reference#numbers-dates-and-times)